# Builds fine, but highlighted errors in Eclipse CDT C++ project

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have created simple C++ CMake project. Project compiles fine, but I see errors highlighted in source code like `Symbol 'std' could not be resolved`:

[image]

How to fix that?

In case I create CDT managed build project I don't see any errors. Why?

Comment: Have you tried restarting it? If so, have you tried turning off any extensions you may have?

Comment: I tried to restart it, but this not helped. I have fresh Eclipse CDT with all defaults installed

Comment: How to know what extensions I have?